# Windows phone app crashes on startup

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I've created an app that is published on all markets but my dev account is registered on US market. The problem is that my app has russian text in it , when I debug it with visual studio it works but when I download it on market it crashes immediately on startup. When I change the language to russian it seems to work. What's the problem here?

Comment: First and foremost, when you say that you debugged with VS, Did you only run the app in the emulator? Have you tested it on a real device, switching the device language? It might also be a good idea to embed some analytics in your device so that you have visibility on un-handled errors. Your dev dashboard might be able to reveal the cause of the crash, I usually embed better diagnostic analytics services which give you real-time error reporting. You can usually sign up for free accounts up to a certain amount of users from the usual suspects.

Comment: i have tested it on a real device, and when i change language it works. In the dev dashboard i have no crash reports.

Comment: What do you do on start up? Do you add voice commands, or something else? Did you try submitting your app as beta? If so, you could quickly submit another beta sending you the crash log with stack trace etc.

Comment: Where in the app do you have Russian text (are you displaying it/sending it)? Also, where do you change the language that it 'works' afterwards?

Comment: Ok One of the possible solutions :  you might be testing the app publishing its debug version ... try changing the deployment mode to release and then check if you get some exceptions

Comment: everything is done correctly, release configuration everything, it's simply not starting